# Where should I use 租借 {そしゃく} or 賃貸 {ちんたい} or [リース ]{りーす}?

Tags: word-choice, words, usage

I'm a beginner in Japanese. So far I learned the following three words have the same meaning - **Lease** (noun).

1. [租借]{そしゃく}
2. [賃貸]{ちんたい}
3. [リース]{りーす}

Where should I use them appropriately and what are the differences among them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a beginner, you would not need to know ***any*** of the three words if you want to know the truth.  Seriously, you would clearly need to know at least a few thousand other words already to use any one of those three correctly and naturally in a sentence.

Above is my answer in all honesty, but in case you insist...

「租借」 is the leasing of a territory between two countries.  A good example would be that between England and China regarding Hong Kong that ended in 1997.  「租借」 is ***far*** from being an everyday word because it simply does not happen everyday.

「賃貸」 is an everyday word among adults, if not among children.  It means "renting" ("letting" in British English?) a house, apartment, etc. for money.  You can talk about renting  a place by using the easier verbs 「[貸]{か}す」 and 「[借]{か}りる」 instead of using the somewhat technical noun 「賃貸」.

「リース」, of course, means "lease".  In real life, it is most often used in business to describe the (long-time) leasing of machines and equipment such as copy machines, vehicles, etc.　Not exactly an everyday word for everyone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure about your first paragraph. I learned the word 賃貸 when I developed a real estate website in Japanese. *(So, I don't agree with what you said "you would not need to know **any** of the three words")*. Then I learned the other two words (synonyms of 賃貸) from google translate. That's why I'm curious to know about them and I think I should learn them. In fact, I'm not sure how to find out and learn those kinds of words - different words in same meaning or different words (kanji) in same pronunciation.

Comment: It will be great if there is any recommendation for Japanese-English dictionary that could explain the meaning and the usage of each word.